# Trouble printing decimal to binary number properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to write code to print the binary representation of a number. This was my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getBinary(int num);
int main(void) {
    int num = 2;
    getBinary(num);
    return 0;
}

void getBinary(int num) {
    int mask = 1 << 31, i;
    int temp;

    for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        temp = num & mask;
        if (temp > 0)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And this doesn't work. If i make num = 2 my output will be ...0011. This is the answer I was given:

```
void getBinary(int);

int main()
{
    int num=0;
    printf("Enter an integer number :");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\nBinary value of %d is =",num);
    getBinary(num);
    return 0;
}

/*Function definition : getBinary()*/
void getBinary(int n)
{
    int loop;
    /*loop=15 , for 16 bits value, 15th bit to 0th bit*/
    for(loop=15; loop>=0; loop--)
    {
        if( (1 << loop) & n)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
}
```

and this will give the correct output. Why? What is different between my code and this. Aren't they doing the same thing with the solution doing it in fewer steps?

Comment: Hint: Print out your value of `mask` on each iteration of the loop. Is it what you expect? Then look up "signed integer right shift".

Comment: IIRC `1<<31` is undefined behavior. Secondly `mask >> 1` would possibly and usually trigger sign extension because your initial `mask` value is possibly interpreted as a negative value.

Comment: @GregHewgill I changed my definition so that mask would be unsigned and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getBinary(int num);
int main(void) {
    unsigned int num = 2;
    getBinary(num);
    return 0;
}

void getBinary(int num) {
    unsigned int mask = 1 << 31;
    int i;
    unsigned int temp;

    for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        temp = num & mask;
        if (temp > 0)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

For those curious, this is the correct answer. Just make the mask unsigned.

Comment: `1 << 31` still invokes undefined behavior. Make it `1U << 31`.

Comment: FYI 6.5.10.3 says "usual arithmetic conversions" will be performed if you use bitwise and operator on signed and unsigned operands.  Then 6.3.1.8 requires the signed type be converted the unsigned type. Then 6.3.1.3.2 requires such conversion follow the "2's compliment" convention. This means your code will print out the "2's compliment" representation regardless what the implementation actual does.

Comment: So what you're saying is when the math is done, it's done as if the integer is unsigned if it was declared as such, but if I tried to print it out, it would print as if it were signed? Why would it do that if the variable was declared as unsigned?

Comment: @Nick: These are language lawyerish considerations you might want to ignore: the representation of 32-bit `-1` in sign+magnitude is `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000001` whereas it is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in 2s complement and `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110` in one's complement.  The code above will print the 2s complement representation even on the vanishingly rare machines that use other integer representations, while the answer you were given would print the low order 16 bits of the native representation.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in the code:

- `1 << 31` invokes undefined behavior because of signed arithmetic overflow. On your platform it most likely produces the value `INT_MIN`, that has the expected bit configuration but is negative.
- `temp > 0` might fail incorrectly if `num < 0`, because the sign bit will make `temp` negative too.
- shifting `mask` to the right when its value is negative has an implementation defined result: On your platform it duplicates the sign bit, therefore `mask` will not have a single bit as expected, but all bits set above the current one. This explains the observed behavior.

You should use type `unsigned int` in function `getBinary` for `num`, `temp` and `mask` to get correct behavior.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getBinary(unsigned int num);

int main(void) {
    unsigned int num = 2;
    getBinary(num);
    return 0;
}

void getBinary(unsigned int num) {
    unsigned int mask = 1U << 31;
    unsigned int temp;

    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        temp = num & mask;
        if (temp != 0)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The proposed solution only prints 16 bits, which may or may not have been the specification. If the `int` type is larger than 16 bits, the bit shift will not overflow and everything is fine.  If `int` has 16 bits, `1 << 15` invokes undefined behavior, so the solution is not strictly correct, but will function on most current platforms.

Here is a simpler solution:

```
void getBinary(unsigned int num) {
    for (int shift = 32; shift-- > 0;) {
        putchar('0' + ((num >> shift) & 1));
    }
    putchar("\n");
}
```

Initialize `shift` to `16` to print only the low order 16 bits.

Comment: Ya I realized that they needed to be unsigned. Thanks for your help!